# The difference between += and =+

Tags: java, syntax, operators

I've misplaced `+=` with `=+` one too many times, and I think I keep forgetting because I don't know the difference between these two, only that one gives me the value I expect it to, and the other does not.

Why is this?

Answer (score 97, accepted):

`a += b` is short-hand for `a = a + b` (though note that the expression `a` will only be evaluated once.)

`a =+ b` is `a = (+b)`, i.e. assigning the unary `+` of `b` to `a`.

Examples:

```
int a = 15;
int b = -5;

a += b; // a is now 10
a =+ b; // a is now -5
```

Comment: Helpful and concise  answer but, forgive me for being new, what is meant by unary `+` of b? Isn't `a = b` same as `a =+ b` according to this?

Comment: @deadcode Yes! The unary `+` isn't the "make operand positive" operator, it's actually the "identity" operator. It's... not that helpful :)

Comment: The way `a = +b` works is as follows:
`int b = -5;`
Variable a is now set to a unary of b when we write `a = +b;`
So, `a = + (-5)`, resulting in `a=-5`

Answer (score 23):

`+=` is a compound assignment operator - it *adds* the RHS operand to the existing value of the LHS operand.

`=+` is just the assignment operator followed by the unary + operator. It *sets* the value of the LHS operand to the value of the RHS operand:

```
int x = 10;

x += 10; // x = x + 10; i.e. x = 20

x =+ 5; // Equivalent to x = +5, so x = 5.
```

Answer (score 11):

`+=` → Add the right side to the left

`=+` → Don't use this. Set the left to the right side.

Comment: +1 for "don't use this"  If used intentionally, the intent is probably to confuse.  If used unintentionally, it is a bug.

Answer (score 5):

`a += b` equals `a = a + b`. `a =+ b` equals `a = (+b)`.

Answer (score 3):

It's simple.

`x += 1` is the same as `x = x + 1` while

`x =+ 1` will make `x` have the value of (positive) one

Answer (score 3):

```
x += y
```

is the same as

```
x = x + y
```

and

```
x =+ y
```

is wrong but could be interpreted as

```
x = 0 + y
```

Answer (score 0):

Because `=+` is not a Java operator.

Answer (score 0):

Some historical perspective: Java inherited the `+=` and similar operators from C.  In very early versions of C (mid 1970s), the compound assignment operators had the "=" on the left, so

```
x =- 3;
```

was equivalent to

```
x = x - 3;
```

(except that `x` is only evaluated once).

This caused confusion, because

```
x=-1;
```

would decrement x rather than assigning the value -1 to it, so the syntax was changed (avoiding the horror of having to surround operators with blanks: `x = -1;`).

(I used `-=` and `=-` in the examples because early C didn't have the unary `+` operator.)

Fortunately, Java was invented long after C changed to the current syntax, so it never had this particular problem.